# In Azure Logic App, how can I remove the T time part from a date contained in some results

Tags: json, date, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App which runs a Stored Procedure.  That Stored Procedure returns some results, which are turned into a CSV Table, saved as a Blob file, and then e-mailed out.  There is a column in the results which is just a Date field but somewhere along the way Azure has added a Timestamp to the results which I want to remove - how can I do this?

For example: 2018-07-18T00:00:00

Below is the Schema details written in the Parse JSON step.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "Table1": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "BusinessArea": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "CaseID": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "CaseOpenedDate": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Lead": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you tell me which step you got this error, I guess it was already happening in `Initialize variable`. If so, can you change the type of date to string when querying date in `Execute Stored Procedure`?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear but I don't get an error.  The Logic App completes every step successfully.  The problem is that the Logic App turns the SQL "CaseOpenedDate" field into a datetime when I want it to remain as a date - how and in which step can I enforce this?  Or do I need to create a new step to amend the data in the CSV table?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t describe it clearly. I want to know which step the `CaseOpenedDate` become `2018-07-18T00:00:00` from `2018-07-18`.

Comment: It's in the Stored Procedure output, which I didn't expect. The SQL in the Stored Procedure itself has CAST(CaseOpenedDate AS DATE) so I would have thought the output would recognise that?  Anyway, I amended the SQL Procedure to CAST(CaseOpenedDate AS VARCHAR(10)) and that has worked.  The Time stamp is no longer added and the data looks like a normal date.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I amended the SQL Procedure to CAST(CaseOpenedDate AS VARCHAR(10)) and that has worked.  The Time stamp is no longer added and the data looks like a normal date.
Thank you Frank Gong for helping me work this out.